# equivalent of following code in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework

I'm having trouble updating this code from angularjs ad angular 2, thank you for any help

```
 if (settings != null && settings.checkSubscriptionForVip === true) {
            return this.user.hasVipAccess().then(function(hasVipAccess) {

              hasVipAccess ? deferred.resolve() : deferred.reject("NO_VIP");
              return;
            });
          } else {
            deferred.resolve();
            return;
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

You neeed to have a boolean variable defined in your component and assign the result in to that,

```
hasVipAccess : boolean = false;

if (settings != null && settings.checkSubscriptionForVip === true) {
            this.user.hasVipAccess().then(function(access) {
               this.hasVipAccess = access;               
            });
          } else {
          this.hasVipAccess = access;
 }
```

However if you do not need to set boolean variable, just return the result